# How to Add HTML to TextView?

Tags: android, textview

How to add html page on TextView final TextView titleTextView = (TextView)?

```
private void renderViewIngredients()
{
    // reference
    final TextView titleTextView = (TextView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_ebook_detail_ingredients_title);
    final ViewGroup containerViewGroup = (ViewGroup) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_ebook_detail_ingredients_container);
    final Button clearButton = (Button) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_ebook_detail_ingredients_clear);
    final Button recalculateButton = (Button) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_ebook_detail_ingredients_recalculate);

    // title
    if(mRecalculatedServings==mRecipe.getServings())
    {
        titleTextView.setText(R.string.fragment_ebook_detail_ingredients_title);
    }
    else
    {
        titleTextView.setText(getString(R.string.fragment_ebook_detail_ingredients_title_recalculated, mRecalculatedServings));
    }
```

Comment: Have you tested my answer? does it work or shall I update my answer? remember you have to mark one answer as acorrect if it solved your problem (Green check)

Answer (score 1):

> How to add html page on TextView

Since you are getting the `String` from `strings.xml` I recommend you to use the [`CDATAsection`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/w3c/dom/CDATASection.html), as follow:

```
<string name="fragment_ebook_detail_ingredients_title"><![CDATA[<p><b>YourEbookDetailWithBold</b><p>]]></string>
```

Then at the time you want to use it you have to use the [`Html.fromHtml()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String))

```
titleTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.fragment_ebook_detail_ingredients_title)));
```

### Edit

When I saw :

> How to add html page on TextView

I thought about a link html, so if you have a link follow these steps if not don't read more.

Make sure that your `TextView` in your `xml` has this

```
android:linksClickable="true"
```

Then you'll have to create a [`Spanned`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spanned.html)

```
Spanned spannedlink = Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.fragment_ebook_detail_ingredients_title));
```

Then add this line :

```
titleTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

And set text on `titleTextView`

```
titleTextView.setText(spannedlink );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use html tags with a TextView you should use:

```
titleTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("your html string"));
```